# How to hover all elements but avoid some?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to hover elements but not all. In this case I tried all but not the table.

```
$(".modal-content *:not("table")").on("mouseenter", function() {...
```

**UPDATE**

I had a typo, accepting the answer.

Comment: you should see an error in your **developer tools console** because that is not valid javascript syntax ... javascript has at least two string delimiters ... `'` and `"` ... use them wisely - although in this case you probably just used string delimiters where they were not required in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a error with quotation mark. Try this.

```
$(".modal-content *:not(table)").on("mouseenter", function() {...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any idea of how I can say "only this specific element which I am hovering"? -)

Comment: You can use this statement for `$('html').hover(function(){ console.log(this) });` for it. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7nr2odyh/) fiddle.

Comment: for some reasons it is first highlighting elements with the same tag, i even tried $(".modal-body").children().on("mouseenter", function() {

Comment: You can use `:nth-child()` selector for it. Try this `$(".modal-content:nth-child(1)").on("mouseenter", function() {...`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need quotes around the word 'table' at all.... The selector should read:

```
.modal-content *:not(table)
```

Just so it's clear, that selector means "all elements that are descendants of an element with a className of '.modal-content' but NOT table elements.

P.S. - if you're just adding visual effects to elements, you should use pure CSS and not jQuery. For example, to turn elements red on hover:

```
.modal-content *:not(table):hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i know about css but i need js in my specific case due to other reasons

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go (turns red on hover):

```
$('.modal-content')
  .on('mouseenter', '*:not(table,table *)', function (e) {
    $(this).css({ backgroundColor: 'red' })
  })
  .on('mouseleave', '*:not(table,table *)', function (e) {
    $(this).css({ backgroundColor: 'initial' })
  });
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o9nj2saf/1/